# How to Convert String Dictionary to Dictionary and the split into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dictionary

I have a single column pandas dataframe that looks like where each dictionary is currently a string. I want to convert each item in the pandas to a dictionary and then split it out into separate columns.

Current Look

```
0         {'Owl': '8109284', 'county': '27'}
1         {'Kid': '298049', 'county': '28'}
2         {'Tree': '190849', 'county': '29'}
3         {'Garden': '9801294', 'county': '30'}
4         {'House': '108094', 'county': '31'}

End Look

           Item     Count      County   County Number
0         'Owl'    '8109284' 'county'     '27'
1         'Kid'    '298049'  'county'     '28'
2         'Tree'   '190849'  'county'     '29'
3         'Garden' '9801294  'county'     '30'
4         'House'  '108094'  'county'     '31'


Can anyone help resolve this. I've tried a bunch of different things.
```

Comment: related [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval()` to get the `dict` object out of `string`. After that get the items using `items()` method on the `dictionary`. Lastly, construct the dataframe.

```py
import ast
import pandas as pd

d = [[0,         "{'Owl': '8109284', 'county': '27'}"],
[1,         "{'Kid': '298049', 'county': '28'}"],
[2,         "{'Tree': '190849', 'county': '29'}"],
[3,         "{'Garden': '9801294', 'county': '30'}"],
[4,         "{'House': '108094', 'county': '31'}"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['a', 'b'])


pd.DataFrame(df['b'].apply(lambda x: [j for i in ast.literal_eval(x).items() for j in i]).to_list(), 
             columns=['Item', 'Count', 'County', 'County Number'])
```

```
        Item    Count   County  County Number
0       Owl     8109284 county  27
1       Kid     298049  county  28
2       Tree    190849  county  29
3       Garden  9801294 county  30
4       House   108094  county  31
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your dicts is the same (2 keys, 2 values), you can use apply function. 'data' is your dict column:

```
df['Item']=df.data.apply(lambda x: list(eval(x).keys())[0])
df['Count']=df.data.apply(lambda x: list(eval(x).values())[0])
df['County']=df.data.apply(lambda x: list(eval(x).keys())[1])
df['County Number']=df.data.apply(lambda x: list(eval(x).values())[0])

del df['data']
```

Output

```
    Item    Count  County County Number
0  Owl     8109284  county  8109284
1  Kid     298049   county  298049
2  Tree    190849   county  190849
3  Garden  9801294  county  9801294
4  House   108094   county  108094
```